# Working example of autoplay youtube in an iframe using webview?

Tags: android, webview, youtube

Does anyone have a WORKING example of how to get a YouTube iframe to autoplay in an Android Webview?

I am using the standard youtube iframe API
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

These will autoplay on Chrome & Firefox, provided you have the autoplay policy flags set.

They will NOT autoplay in an Android webview.

I have tried:

- setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false) on the webview settings  => no effect
- I can't send the .play() javascript command to the  tag because it is inside an iframe on a different domain.
- I have tried sending the .click() function to the iframe => no effect
- I have tried using the using the YouTube player API
  https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations
  also without success.

Does anyone have a solution?  Seems to me the setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false) should be the answer, but doesn't seem to work at all.

BTW, the problem isn't just YouTube of course.  TuneIn embedded iframes also will not autoplay (by any means I have tried).